# Добавить в словарь все слова, которые следуют после слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Есть предложение

> one fish two fish red fish blue fish

Нужно чтобы в словаре для каждого слова было так.......

```
[fish:two,red,blue], [one:fish], [two:fish].
```

Т.е. чтобы в словаре были все слова, которые могут встретиться после слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) и [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = text.split()

res = defaultdict(list)

for a,b in zip(items, items[1:]):
    res[a].append(b)
```

---

результат:

```
In [63]: res
Out[63]:
defaultdict(list,
            {'one': ['fish'],
             'fish': ['two', 'red', 'blue'],
             'two': ['fish'],
             'red': ['fish'],
             'blue': ['fish']})
```

Comment: Спасибо, долго думал как это реализовать